# Countdown in Python using permutations and lambda

Tags: python, lambda, permutation, infix-notation

I am trying to make a program that solves the following with `permutations` and `lambda`:

You pick 5 numbers and a random number is generated, the aim is to use those 5 numbers to reach the target number. You are allowed to use each number once with as many operators as you want (`+-*/`). I want the program to `print()` all of the solutions

this is the code i have created so far

```
from itertools import permutations
import operator

num1=3
num2=5
num3=7
num4=2
num5=10

class Infix:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __rlshift__(self, other):
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __rshift__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __call__(self, value1, value2):
        return self.function(value1, value2)

"""what the class infix does is it allows me to substitute operators such as +-*/ to functions as follows:"""

multiply=Infix(lambda x,y: x*y) #this is a way of telling it that whenever i call x multiply y is the same as x*y 
add=Infix(lambda x,y: x+y) #same here just for adding
minus=Infix(lambda x,y: x-y)
divide=Infix(lambda x,y: x/y)
"""the way infix can be called is if i say 3 |add| 4, which allows me to substitute 
variables as the operators"""
target = 50

for w,x,y,z in permutations((|multiply|,|add|,|minus|,|divide|), 4): #telling it to substitute operators to the variables
    for a,b,c,d,e in permutations(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5), 5): 
        if a(w)b(x)c(y)d(z)e == target: #works out the sum
            print(a(w)b(x)c(y)d(z)e) #prints it if it equals my target
```

The only error in this code is the `for` loops because i don't know how to substitute both operators and numbers at the same time, all the other parts of the code are absolutely fine.

The expected output is all answers that work e.g. `3*2+5-7=4` if `target==4`.

What i asked this to do is run through all of the numbers with all of the operators again and again to find answers that match the target, and then print them out, but i am having difficulties trying to substitute the number together with the operator.

I thought that `a(X)b(y)...` would work because if you substitute it, it is `a(|add|)b(|multiply|)d...` and so on, but it turns out that it doesn't.

None of these work but i am trying to find a solution that does. It needs to loop through the numbers and the operators at the same time and i don't know how to do it!

### Error when running:

[image: this is the error i get when running]

### `Infix` working correctly:

[image: infix working proof]

Comment: You know how [this nearly identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682451/countdown-python-permutations) was closed as off-topic? **Why have you posted it again?!** Please spend some time reading ["how to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: because i have edited the code and even if i edit the code on the last one it wont get rereviewed

Comment: Editing the code is irrelevant; **you're still asking the same (*off-topic*) question**. Be specific; does your code give errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Can that code be edited to work? Yes, of course. Can you do it? Yeah, maybe, but the evidence so far isn't convincing. Are the pipes `|` valid python syntax? No (and they're not the only thing that isn't). Then why have you put them there? Who knows. Why are you asking for length-5 permutations of four items? Again, not clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe have i missed anything to explain? please tell me and i will edit the code again. i really need this answer and i am willing to do anything to get it. thank you

Comment: You've not added anything I asked for. Stop editing the code, and add details on **what happens when you run it**, and how that compares to what *should happen*. What has made you conclude that the code you have doesn't work? Also, it might be helpful to outline what on earth has brought you to the conclusion that `a(w)b(x)c(y)d(z)e` is valid python syntax.

Comment: Oh, and add which bits *do* work - which parts have you tested and can be excluded from consideration? Do the `Infix`es work? Are you getting the correct `permutations`?

Comment: i think that this may have answered your queries @jonsharpe

Comment: **Are you *kidding* me?!** *"a lot of errors not worth explaining"*? Why aren't they worth explaining? Can you fix them? (Then do so.) This isn't a code-writing service. Have you actually tried to **use** the operators you've created, e.g. in the interpreter, to figure out how to pass them arguments and get outputs? Have you bothered to `print` to check the `permutations`?

Comment: @jonsharpe i have attached a photo if it being tested and working. do you have any answers to suggest?

Comment: @jonsharp i have now attached a photo of the eroor and where the error is in the program

Comment: if anyone has an answer please post i am desperate

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think we get to the bottom of it. You are expecting the "bitwise OR" operators `|` to somehow modify the `Infix` objects, so that when you do

```
permutations((|multiply|,|add|,|minus|,|divide|), 4)
```

they "stay with" the objects. That can't happen; for example, you wouldn't do:

```
x, y = 1, 2
a = x+
print(ay)
```

and expect `3`. Instead, you need to do:

```
permutations((multiply, add, minus, divide), 4)
```

i.e. actually shuffle the `Infix` instances, then apply the operators later, when calculating the comparison with `target`:

```
if a |w| b |x| c |y| d |z| e == target:
```

There are a few other minor errors, but that should allow you to move forwards.

Comment: thank you very much, now i need to work out how to print the infix objects

Comment: I would suggest you proved a `__str__` method, and pass the representation you want to `__init__`, e.g. `add = Infix(lambda x,y: x+y, "+")`

Comment: i would but unfirtunately i dont have enough reputation as this question got voted -2 but i had enough before so all i need is some vote ups!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by; I would suggest you proved a __str__ method, and pass the representation you want to __init__, e.g. add = Infix(lambda x,y: x+y, "+")

Comment: please demonstrate. thank you very much, you are my future role model